# Mockito: how to mock type `.class`

Tags: java, unit-testing, mocking, mockito

I have the method that I want to mock the response

```
jdbcTemplate.queryForList(query, Integer.class, nick);
```

I try to mock it like this

```
doReturn(Collections.singletonList(1))
            .when(jdbcTemplate)
            .queryForList(anyString(), any(Integer.class), anyString());
```

But this does not work.

How can I mock any `Integer.class`?

Comment: Does it send a `Integer` as parameter or an `int` (primitive)?

Comment: It's a call of `jdbcTemplate` where I need to specify element type `public <T> List<T> queryForList(String sql, Class<T> elementType, Object... args)`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You want to mock the call

```
template.queryForList(String s, Class<T> elementType, Object... args);
```

so you need to do

```
when(template)
   .queryForList(anyString(), any(Class.class), any(Object[].class)
   .thenReturn(1);
```

You should cut down your use of `any` though, it's best to do

```
when(template)
    .queryForList("sql", Integer.class, "yourArg")
```

or to combine

```
when(template)
    .queryForList(eq("sql"), eq(Integer.class), any(Object[].class))
```